# How to use printf in GUI output

Tags: perl, printf, tk-toolkit

i would like to output something in GUI but not sure how to do it.

```
our $output=$mw_rtframe->Scrolled('Text',-scrollbars=>"se",-height=>25,-width=>150, -state=>'disable', -wrap=>'none')->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'nw',-padx=>5,-pady=>5,-fill=>'both',-expand=>1);

$output->configure(-state=>'normal');
$output -> insert ('end', " line %02x not match with line %02x : %02x != %02x \n", $address+($i)*16,$address1+($i)*16,$line[$j],$line1[$j]);
```

But when output in my GUI it does not show the variable but something like this

```
8747687line %02x not match with line %02x : %02x != %02x
```

the output is work fine when using printf but cannot output in GUI. Any thing need to add to display in GUI? Thanks

Comment: can i know why this question being devote?

Answer (score 2):

use `sprintf` function to format your data before passing it to `insert`.